# Improve performance of query with correlated subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a table "book" that contains 2 columns: title and price. There are a number of books with different prices. I have came up with the following query, but how can I improve performance?

```
Select title from book as b 
where (
  select count(*) from book as t
  where t.price>b.price
) < 5
```

Comment: Can you mention in question what is required output, that will help us to understand

Comment: When you ask a query-optimization question, you should include the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>` so we can see what data types and indexes you have. Help us to help you!

Comment: what is < 5? do you want to limit the search results? if that is the case, you could use "limit 5"

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?  Also, what is your intended logic should there be two or more books tied for the same price?

Comment: Use explain to see where you need an index

Comment: Are you asking for the titles of the 5 most expensive books?  If so a deleted answer was good.  If not, tell us what you want.

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly. Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We need row counts because that can affect query planning. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well. If you have no indexes, visit http://use-the-index-luke.com.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL 8+ or later, then we can easily use `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT title, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY price DESC) rn
    FROM book
)

SELECT title
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 5;
```

This doesn't take into account the possibility of two or more books being tied for the same price.  In that case, we might use a rank analytic function instead of row number.